# Google Tag Manager and Collect tracking code

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Collect tracking code implemented via Google Tag Manager  should have some difference compared to the documentation? Asking that because is Not showing under the status Tab in Einstein predictive email. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the different parameters present in your Data Layer, and fetch it from there, within Google Tag Manager. These need to be created as variables, before they can be included in the Collect Code.

The specific implementation details will differ, based on the structure of the Data Layer, so it is difficult to provide an exact specification which you can apply directly.

If you believe your Collect Code is implemented correctly in Google Tag Manager, you can verify use it Chrome Developer Tools. After opening it, go to Network tab, and put *igo* in the search box. This will show you any calls being made to Collect Code/Marketing Cloud. See an example of this below. This is actually from an implementation where Collect Code is implemented using Google Tag Manager:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

Comment: We've faced the same issue, we've installed Einstein Collect Codes on Google Tag Manager, but under status Tab in Einstein predictive email we can't see codes successfully collected.

Lukas, in order to verify if our collect codes are implemented correctly, could you please explain if we need to use Chrome Developer Tools on website where collect codes are installed, on GTM or in Marketing Cloud page? Moreover, in developer tools we can see only the calls being made or also the body of these calls?

Comment: You should use the dev tools on pages where collect code is installed, not within MC. And yes, all details about the call are visible there.

Comment: I very appreciate your support. To confirm, in dev tools should we see all the collect codes installed in the page (e.g. base tracking, Track Items Viewed, Track Items in Shopping Cart, etc.) and open any script to see the body of the codes to analyze it? If yes, the code I see is exactly as it has been entered at the time of configuring it via Google Tag Manger?

Comment: My need is to understand if there is a specific syntax I need to use when implementing the collect code from Google tag manager or it’s exactly as described in MC documentation. Additionally, clearly any specific implementation differs based on the structure of the Data Layer, but there is any syntax to follow when by google tag manager it’s implemented the data fetch from the data layer and put into variable to be then used by the collect code?

Comment: I believe that it could be really great if you could please share the website link where the collect codes are successfully installed via GTM (maybe the url where you caught the previous screenshot) in order to compare and find any errors in our codes

Comment: Hi @EmanuelaGiraudo
You should just follow the guidelines on the "Implementation" page, under Einstein Recommendations. The collect code doesn't change, when used in GTM. The calls and parameters are exactly the same. As I have written before, it is hard to advise on the details, as no two GTM implementations are the same.

Comment: @EmanuelaGiraudo happy to hear! Remember to mark te answer as accepted

Comment: @[Lukas Lunow] how can i mark it as accepted?

Comment: Ok i succeded in marking accepted